# i can't install my pod,what is 'Could not load keyring'

Tags: ios, cocoapods-1.0.1

I used `pod install` command, but I'm getting the following errors

> [!] Unable to find a specification for 'Keys'.

and

> [!] Unable to load a podspec from `Keys.podspec`, skipping: Could not
>   load keyring

What could be the problem?

Comment: Try updating cocoapods and restart.

Comment: Is `Keys.podspec` for a custom pod of yours? Try running `pod spec lint` on it to make sure it's valid. If not maybe update the question and share the spec so somebody can help out. Sounds like it's invalid.